# Migrating from Google App Engine Backends to Modules

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Google has deprecated its [Backends API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/backends) and has been telling all users to migrate to the [Modules API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/) for GAE projects.

After updating my `app.yaml` and clicking the migrate button in the  *Application Settings>Performance* page, my application is still giving me this error:

```
WARNING  2014-08-26 13:49:57,888 backends.py:55] The Backends API is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please migrate to the Modules API as soon as possible.
```

**Why is GAE still identifying my application as using the Backends API?**

My `app.yaml` file:

```
    application: app-name
    version: baseline 
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1 
    threadsafe: true

    instance_class: F4
    automatic_scaling:
      max_idle_instances: 10
      min_pending_latency: 10ms
      max_pending_latency: 8s

    builtins:
    - deferred: on
    - admin_redirect: on
    - appstats: on
    - remote_api: on

    includes:
    - config/index.master.yaml

    libraries:
    - name: jinja2
      version: latest
    - name: lxml
      version: latest
    - name: webob
      version: latest
    - name: numpy
      version: latest
    - name: webapp2
      version: latest
    - name: ssl
      version: latest
    - name: pycrypto
      version: latest

    skip_files:
    - ^(.*/)?.*\.coffee
    - ^(.*/)?.*\.scss
    - ^(.*/)?app\.yaml
    - ^(.*/)?app\.yml
    - ^(.*/)?index\.yaml
    - ^(.*/)?index\.yml
    - ^(.*/)?#.*#
    - ^(.*/)?.*~
    - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]
    - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*
    - ^(.*/)?\..*
    - ^/docs*
```

**Edit**. My app is not importing the backends module directly, but appears to be importing it directly through the Admin Panel library.  The error is triggered whenever the admin panel page is loaded, using this script handler:

```
- url: /googleadmin.*
   script: google.appengine.ext.admin.application 
   login: admin
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be you still have a backend import somewhere in your code?

Looking at the warning, seems like you're still using "backends.py"

One interesting thing that happened in my team when we were working on different projects is that we received these deprecated calls on APIs we didn't EVEN use.  Seems like internally some "new" APIs use the deprecated ones, which can cause these errors.  I don't think it's risky or dangerous, but definitely not the behaviour one would expect.

Comment: Thank you.  After consulting the logs, it is from an external library--Google's own Admin script handler (which one needs to define manually like I have in order to change the route name).

Comment: yeah as I said, they use their own internal deprecated APIs here and there.  I don't think it'll ever "break" something, because deprecated just seems to mean "won't improve from now on", but it IS a weird behaviour